# how to get current cursor position in MASM

Tags: assembly, masm, irvine32

I am writing an IQ test generation program in which i have to randomly generate questions that will include verbal non verbal questions. For generating non verbal questions i want to display questions in which alphabets and letters will appear in circular or triangular shape.

But i am not sure how to position them. E.g in a non verbal question i want to position alphabets and numbers in triangular shape by writing this code:

```
mov al, alpha 
call writechar
add dl, 4
call gotoxy
mov al, num
call writedec 
sub dl, 2
add dh, 1
call gotoxy
mov al, alpha 
call writechar
```

This is what i already know

> dh= rows
>
> dl=columns
>
> call gotoxy

Gotoxy positions cursor relative to starting position of console, not relative to current position.This is the problem that i'm getting.

I assume there should be a way of getting current cursors position so that i can position cursor back and forth by adding and subtracting from current value of **dh** and **dl** while generating shapes in series.

Comment: There's no `gotoxy` generic assembly function known to everyone, so you must be using some kind of support library, which contains such function. Check what kind of library you are using, and it's documentation (or it's source, if source is available). Maybe this is Irvine library? The 32 bit windows variant? Then you can try http://programming.msjc.edu/asm/help/index.html ... There's no function to read cursor position in Irvine lib, you can either use the underlying windows API call, or avoid that need completely by redesigning logic of your code.

Comment: If it's Irvine32 library, then the `gotoxy` (and other calls like `writedec` and `writechar`) will NOT modify value in `dx` register, so you can keep adjusting `dh/dl` all the time in similar code like you posted, it will preserve it's value. All Irvine lib calls preserve all register values, except output registers returning the function value. But the `writechar` itself probably moves the internal console cursor by 1 char, so the next `writechar` will not overwrite the previous one (while your `dx` is not affected by `call write***`). = it's not clear, what you are asking/what is not working

Comment: If this is about initial position, then design the screen, how it should look... are you redrawing whole screen for every question? Then you can design exactly where do you want to start the drawing initially, you don't need to read the old cursor position, just redraw the screen as needed and place everything on planned positions. (look for some kind of "clear screen" .. I never used Irvine32, so I'm not sure how that console thing works) Keep experimenting for a while)

Comment: yes i'm using irvine32 library

Comment: are you sure it's not the 16 bit DOS variant? From the code you posted it's not obvious, as you are using only 8 and 16 bit registers, so this kind of code would look the same in both target platforms, but it may be crucial in understanding the console behaviour, because windows "console" is emulated thing (like it can be resized to some weird size like 174x33), while DOS has HW text mode supported by graphic card (with fixed sizes/etc).

Comment: No, i'm not redrawing whole screen nor i'm using clrscr for erasing old console content .Because i'm letting user see what was the last question and what was the score last time.

Comment: so... theoretically, you have (answered) question 5 + score on screen, and you want to print question 6, but you don't know exactly which questions were already printed, and where the console did scroll, i.e. you are not sure on which cursor position the place for Q6 starts? I would still suggest to use `clrscr` and print Q5 + score + Q6, without using console automatic scrolling, then you are back in full control of positioning.

Comment: Or, if you want just to roll new questions on and on, prepare the new questions as full-line-string and use `WriteString` to print next question by full lines (ending with newline character), then you will not need to modify cursor position by `gotoxy`, you will just have to position the data inside the line buffer correctly, when preparing next line for print.   Maybe try to provide some extended example of what you want to achieve, and what info you know, and what is confusing you, because I don't see any major problem, I would create such code by using my own whole-screen positioning redraw

Comment: i am not using DOS instructions like INT 21h etc. i'm not sure about this please correct me if i'm wrong.

Comment: Thanks for writestring suggestion that seems helpful

Answer (score 2):

You can get the Irvine32 help online: http://programming.msjc.edu/asm/help/. There is a WinAPI function specified for getting the cursor position: [GetConsoleScreenBufferInfo](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/console/getconsolescreenbufferinfo). Unfortunately the description of the structure `CONSOLE_SCREEN_BUFFER_INFO` is not correct. The name of the appropriate COORD structure is `dwCursorPosition`.

Here's an example how to use it:

```
INCLUDE Irvine32.inc
INCLUDELIB Irvine32.lib

.DATA
    txt1 db "Current Cursor Position is X=",0
    txt2 db " Y=",0
    BufferInfo CONSOLE_SCREEN_BUFFER_INFO <>

.CODE
main PROC

    lea edx, txt1
    call WriteString

    invoke GetStdHandle, STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE
    invoke GetConsoleScreenBufferInfo, eax, ADDR BufferInfo

    movzx eax, BufferInfo.dwCursorPosition.X
    call WriteInt

    lea edx, txt2
    call WriteString
    movzx eax, BufferInfo.dwCursorPosition.Y
    call WriteInt

    exit

main ENDP

END main
```

Comment: hsu.logdown.com/posts/2016/05/18/masm-ms-windows-programming-3  here are the explanation for all members of structure  CONSOLE_SCREEN_BUFFER_INFO that was unclear to me before an example code.